# Throttling Scala Future blocks when onComplete is used

Tags: scala, callback, deadlock, throttling, concurrent.futures

I am trying to spawn many CPU intensive jobs using Scala [Futures](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.2/scala/concurrent/Future.html). Because there are so many, I need to throttle the creation of these jobs (threads). To do that I use:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
import scala.concurrent._

val numThread = sys.runtime.availableProcessors

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue

implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(
      numThread, numThread,
      0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
      new ArrayBlockingQueue[ Runnable ]( numThread ) {
        override def offer( e: Runnable ) = {
          put( e ); // Waiting for empty room
          true
        }
      })
     )
```

To test this I created 2 very simple functions:

```
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }
import scala.util.Random

def longComputation() = {
  val id = Thread.currentThread().getId
  //blocking {
    println( s"Started thread: $id" )
    Thread.sleep( 500 )
    println( s"Finished thread: $id" )
  //}
  id
}

def processResult[T](r : Try[T]) = {
  blocking {
      r match {
        case Success( id ) => println( s"Thread result: $id" )
        case Failure( t )  => println( "An error has occured: " + t.getMessage )
       }
  }
```

}

I then execute the test to execute the tasks via multi-threading:

```
def main( args: Array[ String ] ) {


   val s = Stream.from( 0 )
   //s.foreach { x => println(x) ;  val f = Future( longComputation ) ; f.onComplete{ processResult } }

   s.foreach { x => 
     println(x) 
     val f = Future( longComputation )  
     val p = Promise[Long]()
     p completeWith f
     p.future.onComplete{ processResult } 
   }

   println("Finished")
   context.shutdown
 }
```

When I executed this, 16 threads were launched (CPU count is 8). The program printed the "Finished" message. The system then locks and nothing else is executed. If however I remove the callback, then the threads are execute *ad infinitum* as expected.

Above I have experimented with `blocking` and also using `Promise`. No change in behaviour. So my question is: how can I throttle the task execution without blocking the callbacks? If this is not possible is it viable to do I/O in the threads (Future)?

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is running in a deadlock. The `threadPool` provided is of a fixed size, so the following happens:
`Future(longComputation)` allocates a thread from the threadpool and starts working. When it's done, the `onComplete` allocates a `Thread` from the pool to execute the provided function.

Given that doing work takes longer than finishing work, at some point, all threads are busy doing work. Any one of them finishes and the `onComplete` needs a thread as well, so it requests the executor for one. Work cannot finish because all threads are busy and the machine stops in deadlock.

We can solve this producer-consumer deadlock by giving reserved resources to the consumer. That way, work is throttled by the fixed-size thread pool, but we ensure that any work that's finished can be further handled.

This snippet, where I've renamed `context` as `fixedContext` shows the use of a separate context for processing the results, solving the deadlock. I also got rid of the `Promise`, that was not playing a real function other than proxying the future.

```
val fixedContext = // same as in question
val singleThreadContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
...
...
def main( args: Array[ String ] ) {

   val s = Stream.from( 0 )

   s.foreach { x => 
     println(x)
     val f = Future( longComputation )(fixedContext)  
     f.onComplete{ processResult }(singleThreadContext)
   }

   println("Finished")
   fixedContext.shutdown
 } 
}
```

Comment: @Dima OP execution context is based on a fixedSize threadpool and runs out of resources. `global` is unbounded and will keep on accepting work, eventually ending with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. The option proposed will run stable b/c work is separated from consumption.

Comment: @Dima I changed the execution context to process the results to avoid confusion and make my point about separating the two pools more clear.

Comment: Initial tests show it works. One question though: why opt for a single thread context? I may stick to this because I will be doing I/O on a single resource but am interested in the reasoning behind this option.

Comment: @user2051561 I used a single thread context to clearly illustrate the point that what we need is separate contexts. In this example, one thread will suffice, but in real life, use resources dimensioned to the usecase.

Comment: Ok, understand.

Comment: This is not a very good solution: first, it violates the original constraint by having more threads than it was intended to. And more importantly, it serializes the callbacks, making the single thread executing them a bottleneck. BTW, @maasg to your point on running out of memory ... you do understand, that your `singleThreadContext` has an unbounded queue (that is contributed to by _all_ of the executions), don't you? ;)

Comment: @Dima - your argument may not always be valid. Consider that the callbacks are only queue when the main tasks have terminated. Because we throttle the main tasks, then the callbacks are also throttled. The OOM error would only be an issue if the callbacks took much longer to execute than the main tasks. In my case this is not so - I will be simply recording the results while the main tasks are CPU intensive.

Comment: @user2051561 The callbacks don't have to take "much longer". Remember that they are all being executed on a single thread, while the calculations are parallelized. So, as long as they take less than 8 times less time than the calculation on average, you have a problem. Note, that the number "8" is specific to your machine. If you take your code to a 16-cpu box, you will now need the callbacks to be 16 times faster than the calculations ... This is _not_ a good solution, it's fragile, and inefficient. And I am not just saying this because mine is better, trust me :)

Comment: @Dima I will keep your solution in mind - the amount of code to change is in effect minimal. Appreciate you pointing out the issues here.

Comment: @Dima The intention here is to show the approach with a minimal working example. I'm not suggesting that the final solution *must* use a single thread. Let's differentiate between  the concept and the example: The concept is to separate resources from production and consumption. The example uses a single thread for consumption, b/c that's the minimal thing needed here.

Comment: @Dima "it violates the original constraint by having more threads than it was intended to" -> use n-1 + 1 thread. I don't think the approach breaks on that point.

Comment: @Dima re: *"This is not a good solution, it's fragile, and inefficient."* I strongly disagree. Resource separation is essential in systems dealing with processes that have high "impedance mismatch", like heavy CPU and light I/O in this question. Example: A web server will dedicate a thread pool to serve connections while reserving a separate one to do db handling. You may want to fail to accept a new connection, but you want all existing connections to be fulfilled.  This is the same principle I want to convey here.

Comment: @user2051561  I've answered to the "issues". I don't think the arguments stand.

Answer (score 1):

When a thread completes the `longComputation`, it tries to put the job on the queue to execute the callback, and gets blocked, because the queue is full. So, eventually, the first "batch" of jobs completes, but all threads are still busy, waiting on the queue to schedule the callback, and nothing is available to pull off the queue.

A solution? Remove the limit from queue. This way the threads trying to submit callbacks won't get blocked, and will become available to pick up next task.

You might want to have something inserted into your producer loop to slow it down a little, so that your unlimited queue doesn't eat up all the memory. A `Semaphore` perhaps?

```
val sem = new Semaphore(numThread*2)
def processResult[T](r : Try[T]) = blocking {
  r match {
    case Success( id ) => println( s"Thread result: $id" )
    case Failure( t )  => println( "An error has occured: " + t.getMessage )
  }
  sem.release
}

Stream.from(0).foreach { _ => 
  sem.acquire
  new Future(longComputation).onComplete(processResult)
}
```

You don't need your custom execution context with this - the scala's default will actually work better for what you want to do

Comment: Ok now I understand why the deadlock.  Note that as maasg points out, if I use the default context (backed by a ForkJoinPool), the queue will grow indefinitely and result in an OOM error. As for the semaphore I want to avoid all syncing on my part so as to avoid.. of all things deadlock ;-)

Comment: Yes, i know it'll grow infinitely - thus the semaphore. As for "avoiding syncing", if you think, that submitting callback explicitly on a different pool or using a `BlockingQueue` isn't syncing ... think again :) It just adds complexity to the solution, and violates the constraint of the problem (you end up having more threads than you wanted to), and serializing the callbacks, that'll possibly become a bottleneck

Comment: @user2051561 Binding  a producer and a consumer in a single thread like it's done here will only be beneficial if both processes have the same resource constrains and priorities. In this case, a heavy computation tied to a light I/O operation, I would like my CPU threads to be free as soon as possible for them to take on new work, and wouldn't give them the I/O task, which can potentially block waiting for external resources (disk, network, ...)  The # of threads to assign to prod and consumer will depend on these constrains.